# In central-force mechanics, how do we substitute $ξ=\frac{1}{r}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, differentiation

I have taken a look at central-force mechanics in the past, but I still cannot understand how $ξ=\frac{1}{r}$ is substituted to find $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$ in terms of ξ.

So I know from $F=ma$ that:

$$(1)∑ F_r=ma_r$$

$$(2)∑ F_θ=ma_θ$$

Using polar coordinates {r,θ}, the equations become:

$$(1): -F=m\left(\dfrac{d^2r}{dt^2}-r\left(\dfrac{dθ}{dt}\right)^2\right)$$

$$(2): 0=2\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)+r\left(\frac{d^2θ}{dt^2}\right) \implies \frac{1}{r} \left(r\left(2\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)+r\left(\frac{d^2θ}{dt^2}\right)\right)\right) $$

$$(2): 0=\frac{1}{r} \left(2r\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)+r^2\left(\frac{d^2θ}{dt^2}\right)\right) \implies \frac{1}{r} \left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(r^2\dfrac{dθ}{dt}\right)\right)=0$$

Integrating (2) yields:

$$r^2\dfrac{dθ}{dt}=h$$ where $h$ is the constant of integration

Therefore:$$\dfrac{dθ}{dt}=\dfrac{h}{r^2}$$

To obtain the path of motion r=f(θ), the independent variable t must be eliminated. This can be done through the chain rule by calculus:

$$\dfrac{dr}{dt}=\dfrac{dr}{dθ}\dfrac{dθ}{dt}=\dfrac{h}{r^2}\dfrac{dr}{dθ}$$

$$\dfrac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{h}{r^2}\dfrac{dr}{dt}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dθ}\left(\dfrac{h}{r^2}\dfrac{dr}{dθ}\right)\dfrac{dθ}{dt}=\dfrac{d}{dθ}\left(\dfrac{h}{r^2}\dfrac{dr}{dθ}\right)\dfrac{h}{r^2}$$

Now we have to substitute the variable $ξ=\frac{1}{r}$, but how? The answer should be:

$$\dfrac{d^2r}{dt^2}=-h^2ξ^2\dfrac{d^2ξ}{dθ^2}$$ Can anyone explain to me how this substitution is made? Perhaps using partial differential equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very straightforward, really. If $\xi=1/r$ then of course $r=1/\xi$. Plug this into the RHS:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{h}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)\frac{h}{r^2}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(h\xi^2\frac{d(1/\xi)}{d\theta}\right)h\xi^2.$$

Now $d(1/\xi)/d\theta=-(1/\xi^2)(d\xi/d\theta)$, so the RHS becomes:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(h\xi^2\frac{-1}{\xi^2}\frac{d\xi}{d\theta}\right)h\xi^2=-h^2\xi^2\frac{d^2\xi}{d\theta^2}.$$